# Getting error while running jenkins war in command prompt

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have installed jdk 8 and set path in system variable.
 I am getting below error and might be because of that not getting user password to login to local host.

my error are below:

```
Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hudson/tools/JDK
Installer$FileSystem
  at hudson.os.windows.ManagedWindowsServiceLauncher$DescriptorImpl.<init>(Manag
edWindowsServiceLauncher.java:540)
 and 
Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hudson/tools/JDK
Installer$FileSystem
  at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$DescriptorImpl.<init>(SSHLauncher.java
:1550)
```

please help to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

To run the Jenkins WAR from the commandline you would execute

`java -jar jenkins.war`

This will cause the war file to explode itself to a `war` directory and as Jenkins includes a JETTY web server it will "self host" at localhost:8080.  It will take a couple of minutes to do this.  Jenkins will present the new instance wizard screens for you to go through which will install recommended plugins to get going.

Initially you won't have to log into Jenkins as "Anyone can do anything".

The next steps should be:

1. If you are running on windows, navigate to Manage Jenkins > Install as Windows Service and specify a Jenkins Home directory (Suggest `E:\Jenkins` or on a secondary partition or `C:\Jenkins`).  The user doing this will need to be an administrator on the machine for this to work.
2. Install plugins at Manage Jenkins > Manage Plugins
3. Set up Security at Manage Jenkins > Configure Security